# org.json.JSONException: Value All fields must be completed at msg of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to receive a json response from my server but keeps giving me this exception:

> org.json.JSONException: Value All fields must be completed at msg of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Below is the code I wrote to receive the response:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(SetServerString);
JSONArray articles = json.getJSONArray("msg");
articles.getJSONObject(0).names().toString();
in = articles.getJSONObject(0).names().toString();
```

Below is the jSon respond code on my server

```
{
"msg": "All fields must be completed",
"status": "error",
"profile": {}
}
```

I want when the user logs in with the wrong credentials it should return the "status" and its "msg"

Comment: your `msg` tag is String not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: Please show some *actual* sample JSON, so we can reproduce the problem... and please put a bit more time into writing your post in a clear way in future, with appropriate capitalization and code formatting. The more readable your question is, the more likely you are to attract good answers.

Comment: @jon i just edited my question with the actual JSON sample

Comment: Right, so you're asking to conert "All fields must be completed" into an array - why? It's clearly *not* an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `msg` tag is String not a `JSONArray`.

You need to change this way

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(SetServerString);
String msg = json.getString("msg");
```